# iOS6: iPhone app getting restarted on receiving any type of notification in device

Tags: notifications, ios6

While testing our iPhone app in devices with **iOS 6 beta 4,** we found an issue wherein if any notification like reminder alert is received or when we pull down the notification curtain, the application is restarting from beginning.

It never used to happen like this till iOS 5.X. Apple release notes or known issues of iOS 6 beta did not mention anything regarding this.

Did anyone faced this issue?

Any comments on whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check in the app's .plist file to see if application somehow got set not to run in the background.